# Intermittent Nginx SSL handshake error

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I have an Ubuntu server running nginx that forwards requests to a AWS elastic beanstalk environment running an API (partial migration, work in progress).

I am seeing intermittent SSL handshake issues from the Ubuntu side, where the error lists that it is unable to get the first certificate.

I have checked the cert being offered up by the AWS load balancer, and it does include all intermediate certificates etc.

This issue seems to come up every 2 weeks or there abouts and a nginx config reload (no changes) resolves the issue immediately.

Has anybody got any idea why this would happen or why an nginx reload would "fix" the issue temporarily?

Edit:

Example of the error from the logs

```
7292 Error: unable to verify the first certificate
 7293     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1049:34)
 7294     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
 7295     at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
 7296     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:631:8)
```

Comment: Show the exact errors.

Comment: @AlexD I have added an example of the first certificate error, not sure how much that helps though

Comment: It is an application error. You need to go to SO where this error is discussed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs

Comment: Please provide the nginx error logs and the output of nginx -T

Comment: @AlexD Apologies, here are a selection of errors we are seeing (all specific to the /api/jobs/quote endpoint where the AWS EB instance is).

Errors: https://pastebin.com/w9nXQNrb

Comment: @Turdie here is the output of nginx -T (with some obfuscation & non relevant sites removed).

nginx: https://pastebin.com/fUwW1A33

Comment: You only seem to allow TLSv1.2, for backwards compatibility I would recommend to have TLSv1.1 also enabled. See also the https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ for best practices regarding this

Comment: It is not clear who talks to whom and where the errors are generated. I would start by verifying that all systems have up-to-date root CA certificates and all run compatible TLS protocols - TLS v1.2 and v1.3. TLSv.1.1 is deprecated. Then run `openssl connect` against each endpoint.